# Slow instantiation of itextsharp pdfreader

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

Good morning, I'm developing a pdf merger using itextsharp to create sigle files processed then by a printer as unique job. With some pdf (not all) the instantiation of pdfreader is slow (it takes about 1 minute). I've tested Version 5.5.10 and even verision 7 but the problem is still the same (even if version 7 is al little bit faster)

```
Dim document As Document = New Document
Dim PdfCopy As PdfSmartCopy = New PdfSmartCopy(document, New 
FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
document.Open()
Dim numPdf As Integer = pdfs.Count
For intI = 0 To numPdf - 1
 strFile = pdfs(intI)
 Debug.Print(Now.ToString)
 Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(strFile) 'SLOW
 Debug.Print(Now.ToString)
 Dim pages As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
 For intJ = 0 To pages - 1
   document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
   Dim page As PdfImportedPage = PdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, intJ + 1)
   PdfCopy.AddPage(page)
 Next
 reader.Close()
 reader = Nothing
Next
document.Close()
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate
Thanks

Comment: As you say yourself you observe that behavior *"With some pdf (not all)"*. Thus, we need an example PDF for which that behavior can be observed and reproduced. Please share such an example.

Comment: I've hosted a file here https://a.uguu.se/SAwzwnZoiGtD.pdf

Comment: That sample document is broken. Its main cross reference section claims it has 37 entries but it actually only has 35 entries... iText, therefore, attempts to reconstruct cross references during loading. This may be the reason for a certain slowness. (By the way, a hint towards the defectiveness of the PDF is that when you open the PDF in a current Adobe Reader, the reader will ask whether it shall save the changes before closing --- a repair is one possible such change.) Are the other slow to load PDFs also broken? If some are not, please share one not broken example.

Comment: I think you have find the problem, I've noticed that acrobat asked me to save the file,but I've not given it the right attention. All the slow files are from the same customer, so I guess they are all with the same problem. I now have to find a way to bypass the slowness, maibe making a pdf print of the pdf. Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: Ok, I'll make the above an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample document SAwzwnZoiGtD.pdf (provided by the OP in a comment) is broken: Its main cross reference section claims it has 37 entries but the table actually only has 35 entries...

iText, therefore, attempts to reconstruct cross references when instantiating a `PdfReader` for it. This may be the reason for a certain slowness, in particular as there are other weird artifacts in the PDF, e.g. there is a "0.02 w" between the indirect PDF objects 8 and 9:

```
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /ETI /BaseFont /Arial,Italic /Encoding 3 0 R >>
endobj
0.02 w
9 0 obj
```

Such artifacts can also hinder repair mechanisms.